# How to Highlight commands in embed of discord.py-rewrite

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a embed for my bot of discord.py-rewrite

and want to make some commands highlighted just like in the below screenshot
but i am confused on how to do it please help me.

[image: An example of how i want the bot to send a embed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very easy:
Just put ` between the commands ("`code here`"). You can also use * for italic, ** for bold and _ for underline.

If you want to get fancy you can use multiline code: ```. It works exactly like the multiline code in stack overflow with full programing language support! Here is an example using python:

```python
name = input("Hello! What's your name?")
print("Hello", name)
```

**Note:** All of those examples work just as well if you post them in to the discord chat

Comment: then can i increse text size of the title @Nobert

Comment: @BluTenGaming text size cannot be changed in Discord.

Edit: If you are talking about making the text bold, like in your example, I reccomend looking into embeds: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed